# Pandas Dataframe Tuples Index isin: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have a dataframe that uses tuples for the index (edges for a graph), and I want to filter this first dataframe by a set of tuples (edges from a second graph). I am trying to use the 'isin' method to filter the indexes of the first graph by a set of tuples from the second graph:

```
import pandas as pd

index1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
index2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
graph1_edges = list(zip(index1, index2))

attributes= ['apple', 'banana', 'pumkin', 'spice', 'sugar']

df_graph1 = pd.DataFrame(attributes, index=graph1_edges, columns=['Ingredients'])

graph2_edges = set([('a',1), ('c',3), ('e', 5), ('t',10)])

# Problem Code
df_graph1[df_graph1.index.isin(graph2_edges)]
```

I am expecting to return the df_graph1 with only ('a',1), ('c',3), ('e',5) index rows. Instead I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-116c5e1e0cec> in <module>()
      9 shopping_key = set([('a',1), ('c',3), ('e', 5), ('t',10)])
     10 
---> 11 df.index.isin(shopping_key)

C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in isin(self, values, level)
   2766         if level is not None:
   2767             self._validate_index_level(level)
-> 2768         return algos.isin(np.array(self), values)
   2769 
   2770     def _can_reindex(self, indexer):

C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in isin(comps, values)
    419             comps = comps.astype(object)
    420 
--> 421     return f(comps, values)
    422 
    423 

C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in <lambda>(x, y)
    397     # work-around for numpy < 1.8 and comparisions on py3
    398     # faster for larger cases to use np.in1d
--> 399     f = lambda x, y: htable.ismember_object(x, values)
    400     if (_np_version_under1p8 and compat.PY3) or len(comps) > 1000000:
    401         f = lambda x, y: np.in1d(x, y)

pandas\_libs\hashtable_func_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.ismember_object (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:29677)()

ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

I can't seem to sort out what the error means. Any advice?

Comment: Your code works correctly for me (Windows, Python 3.6.2, Pandas 0.20.3).

Comment: It works fine on my side

Comment: Hmm.. my setup is: python: 3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)|
pandas:  0.20.1 ... I'm updating now and seeing if that fixes things

Comment: @JoshuaZastrow you can try df_graph1.reindex(graph2_edges).dropna()

Comment: @Wen reindex().drop() does seem to work, that's pretty cool! Thanks. Since the graph2_edges is just an unordered set, how does that not mess with the indexing of the dataframe (graph1)?

Comment: df_graph1.reindex(graph2_edges).dropna().reindex(df_graph1.index).dropna()

Comment: hahaha very elegant solution. That^^ and the upgrade worked -- I'm now on pandas 0.22.0. Now sure how to close out this question, you all deserve kudos.